# Tkinter: Skip through PDFs in GUI

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter

I am very new to python and want to build a gui that lets you skip through different pdfs. I managed to display the first pdf. My problem now is that I could not manage to display the second pdf and all following. If I only repeat the command to display the pdf, the new pdf gets displayed next to the old one, instead of replacing it. I have been through several hours of extensive googling and could not find out how to solve this. Can someone maybe help?

Here's my code:

```
 from tkinter import *
 import tkinter as tk
 import glob
 from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf
 from tkdocviewer import *

 parent_path = 'somepath\\'
 doc_list = glob.glob((parent_path + "*//*.pdf"))
 doc_counter = 0

 root = tk.Tk()


 root.title('Training Data Creator')
 root.geometry("1000x1000")
 frame_r = Frame(root, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)
 frame_r.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, side=tk.LEFT)

 # creating object of ShowPdf from tkPDFViewer.
 pdf_show = pdf.ShowPdf()


 # Adding pdf location and width and height.
 V_pdf = pdf_show.pdf_view(master=frame_r,
             pdf_location=(doc_list[doc_counter]),
             width=90, height=100)


 V_pdf.pack(side=tk.LEFT)


 #button skip
 def skip_callback():
     global doc_counter
     doc_counter = doc_counter +1


     # Here I want to display the next PDF!!

     V_pdf = pdf_show.pdf_view(master=frame_r,
                          pdf_location=(doc_list[doc_counter]),
                          width=90, height=100)


     V_pdf.pack()
     print(doc_counter)


 button_skip = Button(root, text='skip', command= skip_callback)
 button_skip.pack(fill=tk.X, pady=0)


 root.mainloop()
```

When I hit the 'skip' button, the next pdf from the 'parent_path' is supposed to appear where the initial one was displayed.

Thanks for your help!

Flo

Comment: This is not related to the question, but it seems like you are not using `tkdocviewer` in this code sample. In that case, it's better to remove the line so that when others try to run your example, they don't get a `ModuleNotFoundError` if they don't have this module installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked into [tkPDFViewer's code](https://github.com/Roshanpaswan/tkPDFViewer/blob/main/tkPDFViewer/tkPDFViewer.py) and the `ShowPdf` class has not been designed to load a new document after the initial one.

The reason why the second file is displayed next to the first one is that `pdf_show.pdf_view()` creates a new `Frame` which is then packed on the right of the previous one. So you need to destroy the old one first with

```
pdf_show.frame.destroy()
```

Then, I have noticed that instead of displaying the second document when clicking on the skip button, what is displayed is a concatenation of both documents. This can be solved by clearing the image list of `pdf_show`

```
pdf_show.img_object_li.clear()
```

Here is the full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import glob
from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf

parent_path = '/home/juliette/Documents'
doc_list = glob.glob((parent_path + "*//*.pdf"))
doc_counter = 0

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Training Data Creator')
root.geometry("1000x1000")
frame_r = tk.Frame(root, relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=1)
frame_r.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, side=tk.LEFT)

# creating object of ShowPdf from tkPDFViewer.
pdf_show = pdf.ShowPdf()

# Adding pdf location and width and height.
V_pdf = pdf_show.pdf_view(master=frame_r,
                          pdf_location=(doc_list[doc_counter]),
                          width=90, height=100)
V_pdf.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

#button skip
def skip_callback():
    global doc_counter
    doc_counter = doc_counter +1

    # Reset view:
    pdf_show.frame.destroy()
    pdf_show.img_object_li.clear()
    # Display new pdf
    V_pdf = pdf_show.pdf_view(master=frame_r,
                              pdf_location=(doc_list[doc_counter]),
                              width=90, height=100)
    V_pdf.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    print(doc_counter)


button_skip = tk.Button(root, text='skip', command= skip_callback)
button_skip.pack(fill=tk.X, pady=0)

root.mainloop()
```

By the way, you are importing `tkinter` twice:

```
 from tkinter import *
 import tkinter as tk
```

so I advise you to choose one of the ways to import it and stick with it, rather than mixing both. Furthermore, I suggest you to use `import tkinter as tk`, this way you will not crowd the namespace with a large amount of unknown names that can lead to naming conflicts (e.g. if you import `Image` from PIL and then do `from tkinter import *`, `Image` will be the tkinter class, not the PIL one).